# integration of continuous function defined on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f:[0,1]\to{\mathbb{R}}$ be continuous such that $f(t)\ge0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Define $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$. Then
>
> 1.$g$ is monotone and bounded
>
> 2.$g$ is monotone but not bounded
>
> 3.$g$ is bounded but not monotone
>
> 4.$g$ is neither monotone nor bounded

$f$ is continuous on compact set hence image must be compact say $[a,b]$ where $a,b\ge0$

$g(x)=0$ for  $x\in[0,a]$

$g(x)\ge0$ for  $x\in[a,b]$

$g(x)=\int_{a}^{b} f(t)\,dt$   for $x\ge{b}$ that is constant

hence first option correct

please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost correct. A correct justification of the boundeness part would be: $(\forall x\in[0,1]):g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\leqslant\int_0^1f(t)\,dt$. Hence, $g$ is bounded above. Of course, it is bounded below, since $(\forall x\in[0,1]):g(x)\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $X,Y \in [0,1] : X<Y $

$$g (Y)-g (X)=\int_X^Y f (t)dt\geq 0$$

then $g $ is increasing at $[0,1] $.
or by derivative.
$f $ is continuous at $[0,1]  \implies g $ is differentiable at $[0,1] $ and
$$g'(x)=f (x)\ge 0.$$

on the other hand, $f $ continuous at the compact $[0,1] \implies f $ is bounded.
$\implies \exists M \ge 0\;\;: $
$$\forall t\in [0,1]\;\;0\le f (t) \le M $$
which yields by integration to
$$0\le g (x)\le M (x-0) \le M$$
thus $g $ is bounded.